# jquery masonry does not render

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

I am using Jquery plugin Masonry to display my images on my Rails app. I can't seem to get it to work. I have put my Masonry script in the page itself. I have included the masonry plugin as well as jquery.js file. I have also uncommented =jquery in the application.js file. My Masonry plugin file is in the javascript folder in the assets folder. 
My code is 
    <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery.js" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.masonry.min.js" %>

```
<%= render 'nav' %>
<div id = "jags_show">
<h1>Your Jags </h1>
<div id = "clear"></div>
<hr />
<% if @jags.empty? %>
<p> NO JAGS UPLOADED YET <p>
<% else %>
<% @jags.each do |j| %>
    <div id = "jags">
        <li id = "jagimage"><%= image_tag j.image_url(:thumb) %></li>
        <p id = "jagname"> <%= j.name %> </p>
        <div class="actions">
         <%= link_to "update", edit_jag_path(j) %> |
         <%= link_to "remove", j, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){

var $container = $('#jags_show');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '#jagimage'
  });
});

});
</script>
```

My webpage has not visible change whether i have the script part or not. Would appreciate if someone could explain it to me as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really sounds like you need to spend more time reading the asset pipeline manual.  Based on what you've said here are some things you should read:

1. You shouldn't be "uncommenting" anything in application.js.  Those are not comments, they are directives.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives
2. If you put a javascript file under assets/javascripts you don't need to use the javascript_include_tag.  Most likely you've got something like this <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> in your layout which is including all your javascript files automagically. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization
3. Modern browsers have good tools for inspecting the assets loaded into the page.  Chrome, Safari and Firefox all have good "inspection tools" that will show you network traffic associated wtih your requests.  I recommend looking in there to see what files are being requested by your browser successfully.

Answer (score 0):

did you download the jquery ruby gem?

if not. that might be your problem

add this to your gem file

gem 'jquery-rails'

save it and run bundle install

Comment: jquery-rails is listed in your Gemfile by default.

Comment: i have downloaded the jquery ruby gem already.has to be something else